# Performance implications of many required files in PHP

Tags: php, performance, optimization

Suppose I have over 100 files called in via `require_once()` command. Is this inducing a significant burden over the load of the server?

If so, what are some possible ways I can reduce this burden while still including the same number of files.

Comment: i would say you have a poorly designed application if you called require() for 100 files, but still the overhead would not be great.

Comment: err...zend framework by itself already load like what...60 files...

Comment: and who said zend framework was well designed :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, requiring lots of files has a significant impact on performance because every file has to be read and parsed on every page load.

Using an opcode cache like [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) or [one of its many alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators) will reduce this overhead to almost 0 from the second call, as the file will already be parsed and available in the cache.